# Monaco Editor registerCompletionItemProvider removes the default local variable completion

Tags: monaco-editor

In Monaco Editor, using the standard initialization such as:

```
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "",
    language: "csharp"
});
```

Will have an out-of-the-box local variables code completion. For example, using the standard initializaton above, and typing the code like this:

```
string testVariable = "This is a string";
int aValue = 123;
```

The Code Completion will recognize both "testVariable" and "aValue" variables and show them on the Code Completion list.

But, if we add a registerCompletionItemProvider to the initialization like this:

```
//Custom Code Completion function
function createCompleters() {
    return [
        {
            label: 'customFunction1',
            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
            documentation: "My first Custom Function",
            insertText: 'customFunction1()'
        },
        {
            label: 'customFunction2',
            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
            documentation: "My second Custom Function",
            insertText: 'customFunction2()'
        }
    ];
}
//Register the custom completion function into Monaco Editor    
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('csharp', {
    provideCompletionItems: function(model, position) {
        return createCompleters();
    }
});
//Continue with the Standard initialization here...
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "",
    language: "csharp"
});
```

Then, the local variables is not recognized anymore, only the registered functions are recognized.

How can I register the custom code completion but also still retain the local variables completion? Thanks!

Comment: where you able to figure this out? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 2):

[This comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/21611#issuecomment-284981639) on an open VSCode issue explains the issue well. TL;DR CompletionItems are taken from a list of providers, each of which is scored based on it's specificity to the language. OPs Provider is specific to `'csharp'`. A possible solution is to change the registration from:

`monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('csharp', {`

to

`monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('*', {`

In my own case this allowed a mixture of my custom suggestions along side word-based suggestions. \o/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add something that can match with your functions. If you match all of it you will only find the functions that are in your createCompleters() function. I have yet to find out how to do searching based on what's found in the returned suggestions and also looking into the local variables. The code below works, try it in the playground and start typing "cu". I know this isn't the full answer but hopefully it gets you going.

```
//Custom Code Completion function
function createCompleters() {
    return [
        {
            label: 'customFunction1',
            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
            documentation: "My first Custom Function",
            insertText: 'customFunction1()'
        },
        {
            label: 'customFunction2',
            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
            documentation: "My second Custom Function",
            insertText: 'customFunction2()'
        }
    ];
}
//Register the custom completion function into Monaco Editor    
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('csharp', {
    provideCompletionItems: function(model, position) {

        var textUntilPosition = model.getValueInRange({startLineNumber: position.lineNumber, startColumn: 1, endLineNumber: position.lineNumber, endColumn: position.column});
        var match = textUntilPosition.match(/cu/gim);
        var suggestions = match ? createCompleters() : [];
        return {
            suggestions: suggestions
        };

        return createCompleters();
    }
});
//Continue with the Standard initialization here...
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "",
    language: "csharp"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is not the direct answer to the question**
Few years ago I faced the same issue and stumbled upon this StackOverflow question. As I didn't found any answer anywhere so I raised a query asking the same in the Monaco editor repo.

[I didn't find a way to show some custom suggestion as well as Monaco default suggestion.](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1850)

I got this reply from [Alexandru Dima](https://github.com/alexdima)

> I don't believe 3 is currently doable.
> But from reading the code here -- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/8758dc9dddf95f358eb93c969353e5cf245ed1e4/src/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/suggest.ts#L180-L181 -- I can deduce that the word completion provider is in a different group than the custom completion provider and once you return a result, the process stops and it doesn't get invoked.

> I could not figure out what creates the grouping, but I can see here -- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/8758dc9dddf95f358eb93c969353e5cf245ed1e4/src/vs/editor/common/services/editorWorkerServiceImpl.ts#L76 -- that the word completion provider is registered with * as a selector.

> You could potentially try to register your completion provider with * as well, and then check the passed in model and check if it has your language and only return results if it is your language... Perhaps that would make it that your custom completion provider is placed in the same group as the default word completion provider?

In the same thread, some people came up with some hacks to achieve. Personally, I haven't tested them as I have stopped working on this. But it would be great who stumbled upon this situation and try to experiment with the claimed solutions and put it as an answer here for future visitors.

Hacks as mention in GitHub thread 
[First](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/created_by/@me#issuecomment-753613962) 
[Second](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/created_by/@me#issuecomment-753648781)